# No método "while" adiciona ao array

Tags: php, mysql, json

Eu estou tentando produzir um script que quando faça a consulta no mysql ele retorna um array, até agora ok, mas o objetivo é fazer com que essa consulta vire um json editado.
Exemplo:

```
{"changelog":{"count":2,"news":{"ola":"testando1","ola2":"testando2"}}}
```

E em C# eu faço um código que retorne isso e coloque em uma TextBox.
Porém não sei como adiciona um item em um array quando retorna os dados em array.

```
$array1 = array();
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
   // adiciona no array a $row[1] e $row[2] por exemplo: no lugar do 'ola' fica o $row[1] e no lugar do 'testando1' fica o $row[2]
}
```

porém a consulta vamos supor é de 30 itens a query é limitada a `LIMIT 0,10`

TABLE:

> ```
> CAMPO        | VALOR
> ID           | TIPO INT, NOT NULL, AUTO INCREMENT
> TITLE        | TIPO TEXT, NOT NULL // $row[1]
> DESCRIPTION  | TIPO LONGTEXT, NOT NULL // $row[2]
> ```
>
> `ID  |  TITLE  |  DESCRIPTION
> 0   |  ola    | testando1
> 1   |  ola2   | testando2`

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi, você quer criar um array de arrays e codificar em JSON, é isso?

Comment: sim! depois do news ele vai colocar `{"TITLE":"DESCRIPTION"}` até acabar o array do mysql

Comment: Mais uma pergunta, `{"changelog":{"count":2,"news":` esses dados são fixos?

Comment: sim! changelog é a abertura e count é o mysql_num_rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara vê se é mais ou menos isso que você quer:

```
<?php
$aux = array();
while($dado = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    $title = $dado['title'];
    $valor = $dado['valor'];

    $aux2 = array("titulo" => $title, "valor" => $valor);

    array_push($aux, $aux2);

}
$array = array("cahangelog" => array("count" => 2, "news" => $aux));

echo json_encode($array);
```

SAIDA:

```
{"cahangelog":{"count":2,"news":[{"titulo":"testando","valor":"valor teste"}]}}
```

Answer (score -1):

Veja se isso resolve :

```
$array1 = array();
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
   $array1[]  = array("valor 1", "valor 2");
}
```